# Error : Can't set user=0/group=0 for . is blocking Aerospike amc installation on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, permissions, aerospike

I am installing Aerospike 4.0.13 Community edition on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.4 using the command

`sudo tar -xvf aerospike-amc-community-4.0.13-darwin.tar.gz -C /Library`

as mentioned on the Aerospike documentation page here : https://www.aerospike.com/docs/amc/install/mac/osx/index.html.

Below is the output i get that shows the error in first line. Can anyone assist what could be wrong and why is even `sudo` not allowed to change the user and group ?.

```
x ./: Can't set user=0/group=0 for .
x ./LaunchAgents/
x ./LaunchAgents/com.aerospike.amc.plist
x ./Logs/
x ./Logs/amc/
x ./Logs/amc/.placeholder
x ./.scripts/
x ./amc/
x ./amc/static/
x ./amc/static/css/
x ./amc/static/css/sprite.61d4c164.css
x ./amc/static/css/vertical-tabs.b49e5f07.css
x ./amc/static/css/fonts/
x ./amc/static/css/fonts/icomoon.ttf
x ./amc/static/css/fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid.35b7636d.css
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/nav.buttons.jquerui.b748fa7c.css
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/images/
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqgrid/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/icons.a3745d06.css
x ./amc/static/css/common.fe3b9be9.css
x ./amc/static/css/timeseries.97956565.css
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.9ca06e71.css
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-icons_cccccc_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_glass_40_ffc73d_1x400.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_glass_20_555555_1x400.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-icons_4b8e0b_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_glass_40_0078a3_1x400.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-icons_a83300_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_80_eeeeee_1x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/animated-overlay.gif
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_flat_30_cccccc_40x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_25_333333_500x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/jqueryui/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_30_f58400_1x100.png
x ./amc/static/css/alerts.6b1cd9b7.css
x ./amc/static/css/grid/
x ./amc/static/css/grid/960.6cf2fb18.css
x ./amc/static/css/sprite.png
x ./amc/static/index.html
x ./amc/static/js/
x ./amc/static/js/dev.app.build.f937de6e.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/prod.app.build.f596822b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/setup.c4091023.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/
x ./amc/static/js/views/statistics/
x ./amc/static/js/views/statistics/statview.01077f55.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/statistics/statview.01077f55.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/statistics/stattrackerview.d11b4799.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/statistics/stattrackerview.d11b4799.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/jobs/
x ./amc/static/js/views/jobs/nodeview.2bd7436e.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/jobs/nodeview.2bd7436e.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/backupview.c8d2ef29.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/roleadminview.71f619a4.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/useradminview.effa7b04.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/roleadminview.71f619a4.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/useradminview.effa7b04.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/restoreview.6174ad24.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/restoreview.6174ad24.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/statview.795f13dc.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/backupview.c8d2ef29.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/configs/statview.795f13dc.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/xdrview.edf8fa8a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/storageview.5764a0a0.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/setsview.68d5f84a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/xdrview.edf8fa8a.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/setsview.68d5f84a.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/udfview.32af0717.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/udfview.32af0717.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/storageview.5764a0a0.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/sindexview.3939119d.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/definitions/sindexview.3939119d.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/namespaceview.1b5ae198.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/xdrview.a80260ea.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/nodeview.ca75aed2.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/clusterwidenamespaceview.1f2bff19.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/summaryView.5ea8498d.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/pieview.c8856432.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/nodeview.ca75aed2.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/summaryView.5ea8498d.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/namespaceview.1b5ae198.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/pieview.c8856432.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/xdrview.a80260ea.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/throughputview.3629ebdb.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/throughputview.3629ebdb.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/dashboard/clusterwidenamespaceview.1f2bff19.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/latency/
x ./amc/static/js/views/latency/nodeview.6cf431e2.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/latency/nodeview.6cf431e2.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/nodelistview.d76a1e8a.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/alertview.79a4a08a.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/AlertEmailsView.0279a915.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/MultiClusterView.5af0f272.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/nodelistview.d76a1e8a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/alertview.79a4a08a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/MultiClusterView.5af0f272.js
x ./amc/static/js/views/common/AlertEmailsView.0279a915.js
x ./amc/static/js/config/
x ./amc/static/js/config/view-config.fee67f2e.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/config/app-config.3e72c233.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/config/view-config.fee67f2e.js
x ./amc/static/js/config/app-config.3e72c233.js
x ./amc/static/js/config/var-details.beffc5a8.js
x ./amc/static/js/config/var-details.beffc5a8.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/setup.c4091023.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/jquery/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/jquery/consolidated-jquery-functionalities.min.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/jquery/consolidated-jquery-functionalities.min.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/require/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/require/require.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/require/require.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/d3/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/d3/d3.layout.min.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/d3/d3.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/d3/d3.layout.min.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/d3/d3.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/timechart/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/timechart/timechart.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/timechart/timechart.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/underscore/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/underscore/underscore-min.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/underscore/underscore.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/underscore/underscore.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/underscore/underscore-min.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone-min.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone.poller.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone.poller.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone.js
x ./amc/static/js/libs/backbone/backbone-min.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/spin/
x ./amc/static/js/libs/spin/spin.min.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/libs/spin/spin.min.js
x ./amc/static/js/dev.app.build.f937de6e.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/stattracker.5bf57379.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/statmodel.c7e163c5.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/stattracker.5bf57379.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/statmodel.c7e163c5.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/clustermodel.6a3747fe.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/statistics/clustermodel.6a3747fe.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/jobs/
x ./amc/static/js/models/jobs/clustermodel.3d483358.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/jobs/nodemodel.0540a215.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/jobs/nodemodel.0540a215.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/jobs/clustermodel.3d483358.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/roleadminmodel.3d0c42b4.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/statmodel.ec7da9f5.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/statmodel.ec7da9f5.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/clustermodel.f859cc6b.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/roleadminmodel.3d0c42b4.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/backupmodel.341ec9c8.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/clustermodel.f859cc6b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/restoremodel.e035dfd6.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/restoremodel.e035dfd6.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/useradminmodel.48f5cedc.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/useradminmodel.48f5cedc.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/configs/backupmodel.341ec9c8.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/clustermodel.aff1ac97.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/sindexmodel.cd029d72.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/storagemodel.0b730815.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/xdrmodel.3fb30ba7.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/clustermodel.aff1ac97.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/setsmodel.3e9e7c15.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/udfmodel.91cfc06f.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/xdrmodel.3fb30ba7.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/udfmodel.91cfc06f.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/storagemodel.0b730815.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/sindexmodel.cd029d72.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/definitions/setsmodel.3e9e7c15.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/nodemodel.0cf553e0.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/clusterwidenamespacemodel.600d14fb.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/clusterwidenamespacemodel.600d14fb.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/clustermodel.f817db56.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/throughputmodel.1f013c3a.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/namespacemodel.1e2b9838.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/nodemodel.0cf553e0.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/throughputmodel.1f013c3a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/xdrmodel.666d5c92.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/clustermodel.f817db56.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/xdrmodel.666d5c92.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/dashboard/namespacemodel.1e2b9838.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/nodemodel.2492b646.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/clustermodel.eb22060a.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/clustermodel.eb22060a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/nodemodel.2492b646.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/nodeCentralisedModel.7d5a8e23.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/latency/nodeCentralisedModel.7d5a8e23.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/alertmodel.f6e9c4d5.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/PopupModel.8a2891bc.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/PopupModel.8a2891bc.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/AlertEmailsModel.d2472af5.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/MultiCluster.f44039d5.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/MultiCluster.f44039d5.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/AlertEmailsModel.d2472af5.js
x ./amc/static/js/models/common/alertmodel.f6e9c4d5.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/onepage.813e3792.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/onepage.813e3792.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/
x ./amc/static/js/helper/sessionmanager.431470a1.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/overlay.a57976e0.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/piechart.fac3e9e9.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/login.0fa8109b.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/servicemanager.206ab163.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/job-table.3c69987d.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/node-table.dd1fdf6d.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/toggle.1471e92e.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/drilldown-charts.9dcd9cb4.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/usermanager.df88eb14.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/def-table.b834c866.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/namespace-table.275d6c99.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/usermanager.df88eb14.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/notification.fa6f0fa1.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/modal.fdd7af73.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/notification.fa6f0fa1.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/jqgrid-helper.65ac9a24.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/toggle.1471e92e.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/piechart.fac3e9e9.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/namespace-clusterwide-table.d575aed0.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/util.331b3a6b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/edit-config.d0500e59.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/namespace-table.275d6c99.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/timechart-helper.ea18fd46.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/node-table.dd1fdf6d.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/bulletchart.aac4c829.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/sessionmanager.431470a1.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/AjaxManager.a727d1fd.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/timechart-helper.ea18fd46.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/xdr-table.beb9de93.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/xdr-table.ff39c4eb.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/udf-table.28ee978b.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/udf-table.28ee978b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/set-table.31986cd3.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/sindex-table.a30dd277.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/sindex-table.a30dd277.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/set-table.31986cd3.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/definitions/xdr-table.ff39c4eb.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/AjaxManager.a727d1fd.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/xdr-table.beb9de93.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/login.0fa8109b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/stat-table.3f106869.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/modal.fdd7af73.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/command-line.0f0b69d6.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/util.331b3a6b.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/job-table.3c69987d.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/stat-table.3f106869.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/servicemanager.206ab163.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/authmanager.4f145c9c.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/authmanager.4f145c9c.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/drilldown-charts.9dcd9cb4.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/edit-config.d0500e59.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/namespace-clusterwide-table.d575aed0.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/def-table.b834c866.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/command-line.0f0b69d6.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/helper/bulletchart.aac4c829.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/jqgrid-helper.65ac9a24.js
x ./amc/static/js/helper/overlay.a57976e0.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/namespaces.aeab78dd.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/xdr.05362f2d.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/sindex.5a200a15.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/sindex.5a200a15.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/namespaces.aeab78dd.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/nodes.eefd1492.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/nodes.eefd1492.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/statistics/xdr.05362f2d.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/jobs/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/jobs/nodes.892f4407.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/jobs/nodes.892f4407.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/xdr.8fef353a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/namespaces.8dd2431a.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/nodes.95d594b4.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/namespaces.8dd2431a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/sindex.c8e4c096.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/nodes.95d594b4.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/xdr.8fef353a.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/configs/sindex.c8e4c096.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/sindexes.0ca21457.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/sets.84d682d9.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/sets.84d682d9.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/udf.0c2f014a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/xdrs.ed7a482b.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/udf.0c2f014a.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/sindexes.0ca21457.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/definitions/xdrs.ed7a482b.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/nodes.44bd0431.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/xdrs.084a99d8.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/xdrs.084a99d8.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/namespaces.0dac923a.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/namespaces.0dac923a.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/nodes.44bd0431.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/clusterwidenamespaces.ea536467.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/dashboard/clusterwidenamespaces.ea536467.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/latency/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/latency/nodes.1fd518bc.js
x ./amc/static/js/collections/latency/nodes.1fd518bc.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/common/
x ./amc/static/js/collections/common/MultiClusters.0c9c1751.js.map
x ./amc/static/js/collections/common/MultiClusters.0c9c1751.js
x ./amc/static/js/prod.app.build.f596822b.js
x ./amc/static/images/
x ./amc/static/images/arrow_down.svg
x ./amc/static/images/bg-btn-grey.png
x ./amc/static/images/loading.gif
x ./amc/static/images/arrow_up.svg
x ./amc/static/images/link.png
x ./amc/static/images/cog.png
x ./amc/static/images/bg-btn-blue.png
x ./amc/static/images/favicon.png
x ./amc/static/images/sidepanelpattern.png
x ./amc/amc.conf
x ./amc/uninstall.sh
x ./amc/mailer/
x ./amc/mailer/templates/
x ./amc/mailer/templates/alerts/
x ./amc/mailer/templates/alerts/generic.html
x ./amc/mailer/templates/base.html
x ./amc/amc
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-sig-mac/BCA3bpn8Qvs - Since El Capitan even root doesn't have privileges to modify /usr and its subdirectories other than /usr/local. Perhaps something to do with that.

Comment: Yes it seems to be related to that. But I am looking for any resolution to get it installed ?. Also I am not on El Capitan, see my question above which has my OS details.

Comment: @pgupta said "Since El Capitan," which was OSX 10.11. You are on OSX 10.12 which was released since 10.11.