# Tensorflow C-API Installation failing on High Sierra

Tags: c, tensorflow, macos-high-sierra

Following the instructions from the [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c) on MacOSX High Sierra.

I'm getting the following error:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 17.9M  100 17.9M    0     0  13.8M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 13.8M

./: Can't set user=0/group=0 for .
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I'm following the Tensorflow C-API instructions. Once I download the file, I run the following command `sudo tar -xvf libtensorflow-cpu-darwin-x86_64-1.4.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local` which gives the error.

Comment: You need to be more specific, after which command does the error appear ? There a a few different ways to install TensorFlow on MacOS (Virtualenv / "native" pip / Docker / from sources).

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the post. I'm installing the C-API which only needs the above download + extract to be setup as are provided in the instructions.

Comment: Check [Error : Can't set user=0/group=0 for . is blocking Aerospike amc installation on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821766/error-cant-set-user-0-group-0-for-is-blocking-aerospike-amc-installation-on). In the comments, @pgupda wrote "groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-sig-mac/BCA3bpn8Qvs - Since El Capitan even root doesn't have privileges to modify /usr and its subdirectories other than /usr/local. Perhaps something to do with that."

Comment: Thanks, yes I checked and have answered the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this github comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228#issuecomment-332679274), looks like you can just chown "/usr/local" on High Sierra.

So, I solved this just:

1. run: `$ mkdir ~/tensorflor-clang && cd ~/tensorflor-clang`
2. run: `$ curl -L \
   "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-${TF_TYPE}-${OS}-x86_64-1.10.1.tar.gz" > tensorflow.tar.gz`

We'll create folder for save Tensorflow's source. Then...

run: `$ sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/*`, once we've chown'd "/usr/local", we must extract tarball, so we run `$ tar -xvf tensorflow.tar.gz`

Finally just copy extracted lib and include folders with `cp lib/ /usr/local/lib/` and `cp include/ /usr/local/include`

The problem is now that we must compile our C files with `gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib YOUR_C_FILE.c -ltensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why that error appears, but it seems it can be safely ignored. After running the command, I later noticed that the files do indeed get installed within `/usr/local`.

Also, it seems to be occuring only on more recent version of Mac(High Sierra) and didn't appear on El Capitan.